# Retrieving a random item from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I'm learning Java and I'm having a problem with `ArrayList` and `Random`.

I have an object called `catalogue` which has an array list of objects created from another class called `item`.

I need a method in `catalogue` which returns all the information on one of the `item`objects in the list.
The `item` needs to be selected at random.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Catalogue
{
    private Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    private ArrayList<Item> catalogue;

    public Catalogue ()
    {
        catalogue = new ArrayList<Item>();  
    }

    public Item anyItem()
    {
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());
        System.out.println("Managers choice this week" + catalogue.get(index) + "our recommendation to you");
        return catalogue.get(index);
    }
```

When I try to compile I get an error pointing at the `System.out.println` line saying..

> 'cannot find symbol variable anyItem'

Comment: Not only anyItem is meaningless in SOP, you have a return above that line.

Comment: Heh, lies, it's not the "managers choice", it is selected at random :S

Comment: Lol, why so many up-votes ?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`anyItem` is a method and the `System.out.println` call is after your return statement so that won't compile anyway since it is unreachable.

Might want to re-write it like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Catalogue
{
    private Random randomGenerator;
    private ArrayList<Item> catalogue;

    public Catalogue()
    { 
        catalogue = new ArrayList<Item>();
        randomGenerator = new Random();
    }

    public Item anyItem()
    {
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());
        Item item = catalogue.get(index);
        System.out.println("Managers choice this week" + item + "our recommendation to you");
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Will randomGenerator is null. you need to create it in your constructor. I'll update the code example.

Comment: For those who got here looking for a more concise answer: Object randomItem = list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()))

Comment: If you with Java 7, `list.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(list.size()))`

Comment: public <T> T getRandom(ArrayList<T> list) {
        return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
    }

Answer (score 53):

```
public static Item getRandomChestItem(List<Item> items) {
    return items.get(new Random().nextInt(items.size()));
}
```

Comment: What exactly is being caught here? You should check if the list is empty or null, not use try catch

Answer (score 5):

your print comes after you return -- you can never reach that statement. Also, you never declared anyItem to be a variable. You might want

```
public Item anyItem()
    {
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());
        Item randomItem = catalogue.get(index);
        System.out.println("Managers choice this week" + randomItem.toString() + "our recommendation to you");
        return randomItem;
    }
```

The toString part is just a quickie -- you might want to add a method 'getItemDescription' that returns a useful String for this purpose...

Comment: Hello, this option throws up a null pointer on this line int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size()); when I try to call the method.

Comment: @will, you never initialized the randomGenerator.  Do so in your Catalog constructor.

Comment: You're correct, I did forget, Doh!

Answer (score 5):

Here you go, using [`Generics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html):

```
private <T> T getRandomItem(List<T> list)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int listSize = list.size();
    int randomIndex = random.nextInt(listSize);
    return list.get(randomIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You must remove the `system.out.println` message from below the `return`, like this:

```
public Item anyItem()
{
    randomGenerator = new Random();
    int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());
    Item it = catalogue.get(index);
    System.out.println("Managers choice this week" + it + "our recommendation to you");
    return it;
}
```

the `return` statement basically says the function will now end. anything included beyond the `return` statement that is also in scope of it will result in the behavior you experienced

Comment: The only difference between having `it.toString()` and just `it` is that the former can throw an NullPointerException and the later does not.  If `it` is in a variable, why not return that?

Comment: good point. ill make the change in the answer

Comment: Hello, This one doesnt work. It gives a null pointer for the line int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    public Item anyItem()
    {
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());
        System.out.println("Managers choice this week" + catalogue.get(index) + "our recommendation to you");
        return catalogue.get(index);
    }
```

And I strongly suggest you to get a book, such as Ivor Horton's Beginning Java 2

Answer (score 0):

anyItem has never been declared as a variable, so it makes sense that it causes an error.  But more importantly, you have code after a return statement and this will cause an unreachable code error.

Comment: Hello. How do I declare the anyItem variable?

Comment: You don't want to, not inside of that method. There are better suggestions on what to do above.

Comment: Hello, All of the suggestions above are giving a null pointer for the line int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());

Comment: They were giving null pointer because I forgot to add randomGenerator = new Random(); in constructor. Doh!

Comment: Then either randomGenerator or catalogue are null.  Check them to see if they're null just above this line with a couple of println statements.  Are you calling this code before initializing either of these two objects?  Edit: never mind -- I just saw your reply.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("Managers choice this week" + anyItem + "our recommendation to you");

You havent the variable anyItem initialized or even declared.

This code:
 + anyItem +

means get value of toString method of Object anyItem

The second thing why this wont work. You have System.out.print after return statement. Program could never reach tha line.

You probably want something like:

```
public Item anyItem() {
    int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());
    System.out.println("Managers choice this week" + catalogue.get(index) + "our recommendation to you");
    return catalogue.get(index);
```

}

btw: in Java its convetion to place the curly parenthesis on the same line as the declaration of the function.

Comment: Hello. Ive moved the system.out.println to before the return. But I am still getting a NullPointer error when I try to call the method. It is pointing to this line int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(catalogue.size());

Comment: You have to initialize the random first. The best pklace for you is in constructor. Without initilization the variable contains null that means "here should be variable of Random type". Without it you are asking empty memory space to give you nextInt. Hence the nullpointerException

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the code 
`System.out.println("Managers choice this week" + anyItem + "our recommendation to you");` 
is unreachable.

Comment: The way he was writing his code it would have also caused a StackOverFlow error (with AnyItem ==> AnyItem() )

Answer (score 0):

See https://gist.github.com/nathanosoares/6234e9b06608595e018ca56c7b3d5a57

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomList<String> set = new RandomList<>();

    set.add("a", 10);
    set.add("b", 10);
    set.add("c", 30);
    set.add("d", 300);

    set.forEach((t) -> {
        System.out.println(t.getChance());
    });

    HashMap<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach((value) -> {
        String str = set.raffle();
        count.put(str, count.getOrDefault(str, 0) + 1);
    });

    count.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s: %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    });
}
```

Output:

2.857142857142857

2.857142857142857

8.571428571428571

85.71428571428571

a: 2

b: 1

c: 9

d: 88

Answer (score -1):

The solution is not good, even you fixed your naming and unreachable statement of that print out.

things you should pay attention also 
1.  randomness seed, and large data, will num of item is so big returned num of that random < itemlist.size().

1. you didn't handle multithread, you might get index out of bound exception

Comment: Who says it had to be thread-safe? Best assume it's not. You may even be in an environment where it's mostly forbidden to handle concurrency yourself (EJBs, ...).

Answer (score -7):

Here's a better way of doing things:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class facultyquotes
{
    private ArrayList<String> quotes;
    private String quote1;
    private String quote2;
    private String quote3;
    private String quote4;
    private String quote5;
    private String quote6;
    private String quote7;
    private String quote8;
    private String quote9;
    private String quote10;
    private String quote11;
    private String quote12;
    private String quote13;
    private String quote14;
    private String quote15;
    private String quote16;
    private String quote17;
    private String quote18;
    private String quote19;
    private String quote20;
    private String quote21;
    private String quote22;
    private String quote23;
    private String quote24;
    private String quote25;
    private String quote26;
    private String quote27;
    private String quote28;
    private String quote29;
    private String quote30;
    private int n;
    Random random;

    String teacher;


    facultyquotes()
    {
        quotes=new ArrayList<>();
        random=new Random();
        n=random.nextInt(3) + 0;
        quote1="life is hard";
        quote2="trouble shall come to an end";
        quote3="never give lose and never get lose";
        quote4="gamble with the devil and win";
        quote5="If you donâ€™t build your dream, someone else will hire you to help them build theirs.";
        quote6="The first step toward success is taken when you refuse to be a captive of the environment in which you first find yourself.";
        quote7="When I dare to be powerful â€“ to use my strength in the service of my vision, then it becomes less and less important whether I am afraid.";
        quote8="Whenever you find yourself on the side of the majority, it is time to pause and reflect";
        quote9="Great minds discuss ideas; average minds discuss events; small minds discuss people.";
        quote10="I have not failed. Iâ€™ve just found 10,000 ways that wonâ€™t work.";
        quote11="If you donâ€™t value your time, neither will others. Stop giving away your time and talents. Value what you know & start charging for it.";
        quote12="A successful man is one who can lay a firm foundation with the bricks others have thrown at him.";
        quote13="No one can make you feel inferior without your consent.";
        quote14="Let him who would enjoy a good future waste none of his present.";
        quote15="Live as if you were to die tomorrow. Learn as if you were to live forever.";
        quote16="Twenty years from now you will be more disappointed by the things that you didnâ€™t do than by the ones you did do.";
        quote17="The difference between a successful person and others is not a lack of strength, not a lack of knowledge, but rather a lack of will.";
        quote18="Success is about creating benefit for all and enjoying the process. If you focus on this & adopt this definition, success is yours.";
        quote19="I used to want the words â€˜She triedâ€™ on my tombstone. Now I want â€˜She did it.";
        quote20="It is our choices, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.";
        quote21="You have to learn the rules of the game. And then you have to play better than anyone else.";
        quote22="The successful warrior is the average man, with laser-like focus.";
        quote23="Develop success from failures. Discouragement and failure are two of the surest stepping stones to success.";
        quote24="If you donâ€™t design your own life plan, chances are youâ€™ll fall into someone elseâ€™s plan. And guess what they have planned for you? Not much.";
        quote25="The question isnâ€™t who is going to let me; itâ€™s who is going to stop me.";
        quote26="If you genuinely want something, donâ€™t wait for it â€“ teach yourself to be impatient.";
        quote27="Donâ€™t let the fear of losing be greater than the excitement of winning.";
        quote28="But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.";
        quote29="There is nothing permanent except change.";
        quote30="You cannot shake hands with a clenched fist.";

        quotes.add(quote1);
        quotes.add(quote2);
        quotes.add(quote3);
        quotes.add(quote4);
        quotes.add(quote5);
        quotes.add(quote6);
        quotes.add(quote7);
        quotes.add(quote8);
        quotes.add(quote9);
        quotes.add(quote10);
        quotes.add(quote11);
        quotes.add(quote12);
        quotes.add(quote13);
        quotes.add(quote14);
        quotes.add(quote15);
        quotes.add(quote16);
        quotes.add(quote17);
        quotes.add(quote18);
        quotes.add(quote19);
        quotes.add(quote20);
        quotes.add(quote21);
        quotes.add(quote22);
        quotes.add(quote23);
        quotes.add(quote24);
        quotes.add(quote25);
        quotes.add(quote26);
        quotes.add(quote27);
        quotes.add(quote28);
        quotes.add(quote29);
        quotes.add(quote30);
    }

    public void setTeacherandQuote(String teacher)
    {
        this.teacher=teacher;
    }

    public void printRandomQuotes()
    {
        System.out.println(quotes.get(n++)+"  ~ "+ teacher);  
    }

    public void printAllQuotes()
    {
        for (String i : quotes)
        {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use numbered variables. Also, we really don't need to see more than 3 to get the point