# How to Loop over ten questions

Tags: java, android

I'm in the process of creating a simple maths game. I'm trying to create a loop that will display ten questions, one at a time, to a textview. The user will enter the answer into an edittext, press a button, and then question will be validated and the next question in the series of ten will appear in the textview.

I'm just not quite sure how to get to the next question. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
int x = 0;

while (x < 10) {
  if (i1 == 1) {
    answer = q1;
    editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "+" + random2);
    x++;
  }
  if (i1 == 2) {
    answer = q2;
    editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "-" + random2);
    x++;
  }
  if (i1 == 3) {
    answer = q3;
    editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "/" + random2);
    x++;
  }
  if (i1 == 4) {
    answer = q4;
    editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "*" + random2);
    x++;
  }
}
```

and then the validation button calls this method

```
private void questions() {
  int score = 0;
  int i = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
  if (i == answer) {
    editText.setText("Correct");
    score++;
  } else {
    editText.setText("Incorrect");
  }
}
```

Comment: Cant help with your answer but the whole multiple ifs testing the same variable is a perfect case for a switch statement

Answer (score 0):

Have a method `getNextQuestion()` and call it in the button click Listener. Just change the Text in the TextView by calling

```
TextView.setText(Question)
```

Have an ArrayList of Question and pass the index or count in the getNextQuestion() method to show the next question and increment the index/count after that.

Edit:
Set a field in your Activity as

```
int index=0;
```

and pass this index in your method, which is changing the text.

```
 getNextQuestion(index);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. How do I pass the index in the getNextQuestion() method and increment the index?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following (assuming you want to generate each question randomly):

- Define a `String getQuestion()` method that will return your randomly
  generated question (two random number and a random operand) in a
  String
- Define a `boolean checkAnswer(String question, String answer)`
  that will check the provided answer is right for the provided
  question.

Then, when clicking your "validate" button, you

- call

  checkAnswer(yourQuestionsTextView.getText().toString(),
     yourAnswerField.getText().toString())

  and display "Correct" or
  "False" using `Toast` depending on the result
- call `yourQuestionsTextView.setText(getQuestion())`

Comment: Or justhave a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9420491/random-math-questions-generator-for-android

Comment: I wish to add a score counter if the question is correct. Where would I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Creator***'s way or change the layout with the click event. Every layout will have its own textview and button. You will have just one xml and viewflipper in it. Put linear or relative layouts as many as your questions and textview and button in that layout. In the java file, put

`ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_VIEWFLIPPER);`

`vf.showNext();`

into the click events of buttons. Then it will change the layout and next question will be shown.

Comment: How do I get the next textview and edittext to overwrite the old ones?

Comment: There is a similar work on this site. 
[link](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/29/android-switching-screens-by-dragging-over-the-touch-screen/) 

`<TextView android:id="@+id/q1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Hello" >
 </TextView>`

For example, above the text of the text view is Hello. You will write the question there. Actually there is a better way. You should create your questions in string.xml and referance it in textview like `android:text="@string/question1"`

Comment: Don't forget that they change the screen by touching. You will not use that way. You will add click events for each button you have, and put the code I wrote in my first answer into the click events with corresponding textview id.