# How can I print 1 random string from 4?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

```
String haiku1 = "As the wind does blow\nAcross the trees, I see the\nBuds blooming in May."; 
String haiku2 = "I walk across sand\nAnd find myself blistering\nIn the hot, hot heat."; 
String haiku3 = "Falling to the ground,\nI watch a leaf settle down\nIn a bed of brown.";  
String haiku4 = "It’s cold and I wait\nFor someone to shelter me\nAnd take me from here.";
```

I need to print a random string out of the four listed above. How could I do this? I know I must use random. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

It's better to put your strings in an array.

```
String haiku[] = new String[4];
haiku[0] = "/*your string*/";
haiku[1] = "/*your string*/";
haiku[2] = "/*your string*/";
haiku[3] = "/*your string*/";
```

Then generate random number from 0-3 to access the index of your array.

```
Random randomizer = new Random();         //import java.util.Random;
int index = randomizer.nextInt(4);
System.out.println("Generated random string: " + haiku[index]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this -

```
    ...
    int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(4);
    switch (nextInt) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println(haiku1);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println(haiku2);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println(haiku3);
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println(haiku4);
        break;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your above Strings and use [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate random number for array index.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You should put this strings in an array.

for further reference please chekc below link.
[Retrieving a random item from ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034370/retrieving-a-random-item-from-arraylist)

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number and then access value stored at particular position in array:

```
  Random r = new Random();
  int index = r.nextInt(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
String[] myArray = {haiku1,haiku2,haiku3,haiku4};
Random rand = new Random();
int randomnum = rand.nextint(4);
System.out.println(myArray[randomnum]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String haiku1 = ("As the wind does blow\nAcross the trees, I see the\nBuds blooming in May.");
    String haiku2 = ("I walk across sand\nAnd find myself blistering\nIn the hot, hot heat.");
    String haiku3 = ("Falling to the ground,\nI watch a leaf settle down\nIn a bed of brown.");
    String haiku4 = ("It’s cold and I wait\nFor someone to shelter me\nAnd take me from here.");

    String[] array={haiku1,haiku2,haiku3,haiku4};

    Random rndm=new Random();

    System.out.println( "Generated Random String: "+array[rndm.nextInt((array.length-1) - 0 + 1) + 0]);
```