# How java print a string value from a list?

Tags: java, arrays, random

How can I print a string value from a list in java?

I have an array with more four strings.
I want to print one of the value from the list randomly.

I tried this :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class Text {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String [] array = {"hello", "world", "coucou"};
        List <String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
        {
            System.out.println("String from the list ="+Random.array);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help resolve the syntax for `System.out.println`?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving a random item from ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034370/retrieving-a-random-item-from-arraylist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) class to generate a random number between 0 (inclusive) and your list's length (exclusive), and print the value at that index.

```
Random rand = new Random();
System.out.println("String from list: " + list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before selecting the random element you can create a random number from range `[0, n)` where `n` is the size of the list.

You can use `new Random(System.nanoTime()).nextInt(list.size())` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class ListExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



          String [] array = {"hello", "world", "coucou"};

         ArrayList <String> list=new ArrayList<String>();


         for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
             list.add(array[i]);
         }

        Random rnd=new Random();


        System.out.println("String from the list ="+list.get(rnd.nextInt(array.length)));

        }


}
```