# Select random item in CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

In this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvOm5.png), you can see a `CardView` where each item is displayed one at a time. I have implemented a touch functionality that scrolls through the dataset. I would now like to implement the functionality of choosing an item at random. Here is where the `CardView` is set:

```
package com.chiemy.cardview.view;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

import com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator;
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper;
import com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator;

/**
 * @author chiemy
 * 
 */
public class CardView extends FrameLayout {
    private static final int ITEM_SPACE = 40;
    private static final int DEF_MAX_VISIBLE = 4;

    private int mMaxVisible = DEF_MAX_VISIBLE;
    private int itemSpace = ITEM_SPACE;

    private float mTouchSlop;
    private ListAdapter mListAdapter;
    private int mNextAdapterPosition;
    private SparseArray<View> viewHolder = new SparseArray<View>();
    private OnCardClickListener mListener;
    private int topPosition;
    private Rect topRect;

    public interface OnCardClickListener {
        void onCardClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public CardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public CardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        topRect = new Rect();
        ViewConfiguration con = ViewConfiguration.get(getContext());
        mTouchSlop = con.getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    public void setMaxVisibleCount(int count) {
        mMaxVisible = count;
    }

    public int getMaxVisibleCount() {
        return mMaxVisible;
    }

    public void setItemSpace(int itemSpace) {
        this.itemSpace = itemSpace;
    }

    public int getItemSpace() {
        return itemSpace;
    }

    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
        return mListAdapter;
    }

    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if (mListAdapter != null) {
            mListAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mNextAdapterPosition = 0;
        mListAdapter = adapter;
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        removeAllViews();
        ensureFull();
    }

    public void setOnCardClickListener(OnCardClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    private void ensureFull() {
        while (mNextAdapterPosition < mListAdapter.getCount()
                && getChildCount() < mMaxVisible) {
            int index = mNextAdapterPosition % mMaxVisible;
            View convertView = viewHolder.get(index);
            final View view = mListAdapter.getView(mNextAdapterPosition,
                    convertView, this);
            view.setOnClickListener(null);
            viewHolder.put(index, view);

            index = Math.min(mNextAdapterPosition, mMaxVisible - 1);
            ViewHelper.setScaleX(view,((mMaxVisible - index - 1) / (float) mMaxVisible) * 0.2f + 0.8f);
            int topMargin = (mMaxVisible - index - 1) * itemSpace;
            ViewHelper.setTranslationY(view, topMargin);
            ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, mNextAdapterPosition == 0 ? 1 : 0.5f);

            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            if (params == null) {
                params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            }
            addViewInLayout(view, 0, params);

            mNextAdapterPosition += 1;
        }
        // requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int childCount = getChildCount();
        int maxHeight = 0;
        int maxWidth = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            this.measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            if (height > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = height;
            }
            if (width > maxWidth) {
                maxWidth = width;
            }
        }
        int desireWidth = widthSize;
        int desireHeight = heightSize;
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            desireWidth = maxWidth + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        }
        if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            desireHeight = maxHeight + (mMaxVisible - 1) * itemSpace + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(desireWidth, desireHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        View topView = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        if (topView != null) {
            topView.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }

    float downX, downY;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (goDown()) {
                downY = -1;
            }
            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    /**
     * 下移所有视图
     */
    private boolean goDown() {
        final View topView = getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1);
        if(!topView.isEnabled()){
            return false;
        }
        // topView.getHitRect(topRect); 在4.3以前有bug，用以下方法代替
        topRect = getHitRect(topRect, topView);
        // 如果按下的位置不在顶部视图上，则不移动
        if (!topRect.contains((int) downX, (int) downY)) {
            return false;
        }
        topView.setEnabled(false);
        ViewPropertyAnimator anim = ViewPropertyAnimator
                .animate(topView)
                .translationY(
                        ViewHelper.getTranslationY(topView)
                                + topView.getHeight()).alpha(0).scaleX(1)
                .setListener(null).setDuration(200);
        anim.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                topView.setEnabled(true);
                removeView(topView);
                ensureFull();
                final int count = getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    final View view = getChildAt(i);
                    float scaleX = ViewHelper.getScaleX(view)
                            + ((float) 1 / mMaxVisible) * 0.2f;
                    float tranlateY = ViewHelper.getTranslationY(view)
                            + itemSpace;
                    if (i == count - 1) {
                        bringToTop(view);
                    } else {
                        if ((count == mMaxVisible && i != 0)
                                || count < mMaxVisible) {
                            ViewPropertyAnimator
                                    .animate(view)
                                    .translationY(tranlateY)
                                    .setInterpolator(
                                            new AccelerateInterpolator())
                                    .setListener(null).scaleX(scaleX)
                                    .setDuration(200);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    private void bringToTop(final View view) {
        topPosition++;
        float scaleX = ViewHelper.getScaleX(view) + ((float) 1 / mMaxVisible)
                * 0.2f;
        float tranlateY = ViewHelper.getTranslationY(view) + itemSpace;
        ViewPropertyAnimator.animate(view).translationY(tranlateY)
                .scaleX(scaleX).setDuration(200).alpha(1)
                .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        float currentY = ev.getY();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downX = ev.getX();
            downY = ev.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float distance = currentY - downY;
            if (distance > mTouchSlop) {
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Rect getHitRect(Rect rect, View child) {
        rect.left = child.getLeft();
        rect.right = child.getRight();
        rect.top = (int) (child.getTop() + ViewHelper.getTranslationY(child));
        rect.bottom = (int) (child.getBottom() + ViewHelper
                .getTranslationY(child));
        return rect;
    }

    private final DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            super.onInvalidated();
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onCardClick(v, topPosition);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Here is my `CardView` adapter class:

```
package com.chiemy.cardview.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.chiemy.cardview.R;

public abstract class CardAdapter<T> extends BaseCardAdapter {
    private final Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<T> mData;

    public CardAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mData = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public CardAdapter(Context context, Collection<? extends T> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mData = new ArrayList<T>(items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        FrameLayout wrapper = (FrameLayout) convertView;
        View cardView;
        View convertedCardView;
        if (wrapper == null) {
            wrapper = new FrameLayout(mContext);
            wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_background_shadow);
            cardView = getCardView(position, null, wrapper);
            wrapper.addView(cardView);
        } else {
            cardView = wrapper.getChildAt(0);
            convertedCardView = getCardView(position, cardView, wrapper);

            wrapper.removeView(cardView);
            wrapper.addView(convertedCardView);
            if (convertedCardView != cardView) {
            }
        }
        return wrapper;
    }

    protected abstract View getCardView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

    public void addAll(List<T> items){
        mData.addAll(items);
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public void clear(){
        if(mData != null){
            mData.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Please, put in this question all relevant information and aviod add links to another external resources

Comment: Can you please clarify your questions as it is a bit unclear

Comment: Also, provide some code

Comment: i have edited my question @Razor

Comment: Are you saying you want to randomly select one of the items in your `CardView`?

Comment: Yes , like the lottery. Touch the list with ticks and later stopped and an item to be displayed randomly .@Razor

Comment: Are you stuck with the randomisation of your `ArrayList<>`? Does the touch functionality work fine?

Comment: I want when I touch down , begin to move items.then from one time to stop the move.my problem is move items like auto scroll. and randomisation item.@Razor

Comment: Are all your items arranged in a list form (e.g. one after the other)? Also, do you mean when you touch the screen, you want to begin shuffling through the items and randomly picking out one of them?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you say.@Razor

Answer (score 2):

To randomise an `ArrayList<>`, in your case, this would be the shuffling solution, you can use this code:

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(list_of_items, new Random(seed));
```

You will need to set the `ArrayList<>` back to the `CardView` and your items will be randomly shuffled. To retrieve a random item, visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034370/retrieving-a-random-item-from-arraylist) page to learn about getting a random item from an `ArrayList<>`. See how you go and ask for more help if needed.

Comment: Sorry if the answer is a bit rushed. I'm typing from a tablet and adding code is a bit difficult.

Comment: Thank you for helping. But the first problem I have is that I want to be auto scrolling items.like http://i.stack.imgur.com/WXyzC.gif @Razor

Comment: You will need to implement animations which can be very difficult if you want that kind of scrolling. In terms of your shuffling capabilities, I suggest you randomise the `ArrayList<>` of your items and then chose one randomly like I demonstrated above.