# How to display random items from arraylist<T> derived from a doInBackground?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask

So i was making this app which displays an arrayList of different poems 
I first request the poems from API then the Asynctask returns the poems in the form of Arraylist i wand to show 20 random poems from the list.

This is the Asynctask code

```
private class TitleAsynctask extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,List<view>> {


        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        public List<view> doInBackground(URL... urls){

            URL url = Query_utils.createurl(POEM_TITLE);
            String json = "";
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"this worked");
            {
                try {
                    json = Query_utils.makehttprequest(url);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "make Httprequest works");
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
            List<view> title_view = Query_utils.extracttitlefromjson(json);
            return title_view;

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<view> data) {
            madapter.clear();


            if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()){
                madapter.addAll(data);
            }
        }

    }
```

and the onCreate code is

```
 TitleAsynctask task = new TitleAsynctask();
    URL url = Query_utils.createurl(POEM_TITLE);
            task.execute(url);


            ArrayList<view > arr = new ArrayList<view>();

            final ListView poem_Title_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            madapter = new title_adapter(this ,arr);
            poem_Title_list.setAdapter(madapter);
```

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034370/retrieving-a-random-item-from-arraylist) helps

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

1. Just use a random number generator to generate a number between 0 and the number of entries-1. The disadvantage with this method is that you can get repeats.
2. Randomly sort the list after fetching. You can do this using [Collections.shuffle(list)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) This way you won't get any repeats but you will sort the whole list which could be a waste if there are hundreds of entries and you only want to show 20.

Comment: when i do that it give an exception saying the input size is 521(for example) and the size is 0 , i think that means when i use the ArrayList arr its size is 0, which it clearly is not.

Comment: When are you doing the sort?
You must do it inside the postExecute. You can't do it in onCreate itself since the fetch is asynchronous.

Comment: i didn't sort but still it works until i don't call it to a different method

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow your meaning. Where do you call the method that accesses them?