# Picking a random element from an arraylist and removing it from the list in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a command line type of program that would allow you to play solitaire. I currently have **class Deck** and **class Card**.
In class Deck i have an ArrayList and two methods - one that creates a deck and one that shuffles it. I need to create a method that deals a card - meaning a method that would pick a random element from an ArrayList and it is gonna erase it from the ArrayList. When a card is dealt it is not in the ArrayList anymore, i believe. Here is the code in my Deck class:

```
public class Deck {
   private ArrayList deck = new ArrayList < Card > ();
   private Random randomGenerator;

}

public Deck() {
 for (Suit s: Suit.values())
  for (Numbers n: Numbers.values()) {
   Card c1 = new Card(n, s);
   deck.add(c1);
   System.out.println(deck);
  }
}
private void printAll() {}
public void shuffle() {
 Collections.shuffle(deck);
}
```

I'm really having a hard time with creating a method that would erase the dealt element, what i have done so far is pretty much based on the answers of this problem but it is not quite what i need.
[Retrieving a random item from ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034370/retrieving-a-random-item-from-arraylist)

```
public Card deal(deck) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    Card dealtCard = rand.deck();
    return dealtCard;
}
```

Could anyone provide any guidance for me on this method?
Please and thank you

Comment: `deck.remove(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(deck.size()));`

Comment: I think the better idea is to use `Collections.shuffle()` and then just deal one card at a time off the top or the bottom.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-

Comment: A good place to start is to look at the javadocs for ArrayList

Comment: I did reformat the code, i'm sorry

Comment: @CatV Not really.  Also based upon this code, your class `Deck` is not correct with regards to the positioning of curly braces

Answer (score 3):

Really the entire point of shuffling the deck is to allow you to deal from the top of the deck and get random cards each time. So if the `Deck` class has:

```
private final List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you have called `Collections.shuffle(cards)` then all you need to do to get the top card in the deck is:

```
public Card deal() {
    return cards.remove(0);
}
```

You should also have an `isEmpty` method so that the caller can make sure there are cards left in the deck before calling `deal`. That's better coding practice than catching the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @CatV — also notice the proper declaration: `List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();` ... cards is a `List` and the chosen implementation of the List is an `ArrayList` -- but the code shouldn't care about that choice, so you just declare `List<Card>`

Answer (score -1):

You could use something like this

`Random rand = new Random();`

```
int randomElement = givenList.get(rand.nextInt(givenList.size()));
```

I think this link might be useful
http://www.baeldung.com/java-random-list-element

Comment: This does not remove the card, so the same card could be dealt many times.  See 2.4 _"Select Random Items Without Repetitions"_ in the article you linked to.